# Unity Addressables should only be used through remote servers?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity Addressables should only be used through remote servers? Is it possible to use them without an Internet connection, for example, not include them in the build but store them as links, thereby not taking up the installer's memory (now I'm talking about the size of .apk and .abb builds for android), but I would like to understand that it also reduces the size on other platforms like PC, because I know that using Unity Resources takes up memory in the build, and on the contrary, I want to reduce the size as much as possible, but without an Internet connection, my question is to understand whether it is possible to use this plugin is local and if there are detailed sources where they parse it, then maybe links, I will be grateful, I can’t find a question on this

Comment: How are you going to load something from a link without an internet connection? If your addressable assets are not included in a build and there's no internet I guess you would have to bring the files yourself.

Comment: Yeah your concept is a bit hard to understand.. sure you can ship them locally along with your installer .. but then you somehow need to get them .. so either you ship them with your build or will need an internet connection I guess .. or your users will need to copy them to a specific local folder so your app can later find them .. not really recommendable though

Comment: I understood you! Thanks, but is there a solution similar to Addressable, only local, where I could save space in the installer on mobile platforms, taking up a small amount of space as a link somewhere in the build from where I could download if necessary? For example, if I put the whole scene or textures as an archive or something similar that would take up less memory, from where after I could pull out the full files!

Comment: Well, again: `taking up a small amount of space as a link somewhere in the build from where I could download if necessary` ... how are you going to load this then `without an Internet connection` ... as said sure you can define a local path .. e.g. [`Application.persistendDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) but would need your users to manually place files in the exact correct spot => ain't gonna happen ^^ There is no way to make a build smaller and at the same time ship the build with all data included

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define a local folder where it looks for the addressables. How to bring the files there before you start the game, is then up to you.
This video shows how to use addressables for mods with local files: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bN0hefj_IkQ

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for an official solution, if it doesn't work out then I wouldn't want to use some kind of custom